# Existence of splitting field of any polynomial in $F[X]$

Tags: galois-theory

So I was reading some proofs from different books of existence of splitting field and I don't know why to bother so much about this. I think this can be done trivially.

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial from $F[x]$. Suppose $a_1$, $a_2 ,\ldots,a_n$ be the roots of $f(x)$ which are outside F. Now if I take $ F(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, this is the smallest field containing $F$ and the roots, hence $f(x)$ splits over this field and this $F(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is the smallest one containing $F$. Hence any polynomial has a splitting field.

Am I doing some mistake?

Comment: 1. "Roots of $f(x)$ that are outside $F$". *Where* are they? How do you know they exist? How do you know there's enough of them? 2. "Take $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$". This only makes sense if you have a field $K$ with $F\subseteq K$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in K$ (since "$F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$" means "the smallest field [contained in $K$] that contains $F$, $a_1,\ldots,a_n$". It does not have an inherent meaning. So your argument is basically saying "If you know that there is a splitting field, then there is a splitting field."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not making any mistake, but rather, not giving enough detail: You write $F(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, but you do not define it: note that at that point in the proof one does not know whether there is a field extension of $F$ "containing the $a_k$". In fact, even the $a_k$ are not really being defined. The essence of the proof that a splitting field exists, is to make sense of "the roots of $f$ outside $F$", and the expression $F(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$.

Comment: F(a1,a2,..an) is defined as intersection of all the fields containing F and the mentioned roots and this is actually quotient field of F[a1,a2,... ,an]. This is making sense I think.for eg. We can think about Q(sqrt(2)) as a splitting field.of x²-2.

Comment: Okay I got your point. Since we have only the polynomial provided,we actually do not know from where this $a_k$ are coming from.Could you please suggest me some good book where the theorems are well explained?

Comment: Exactly. You can try Lang's _Algebra_, Part 2 Chapter V. Or Dummit and Foote, _Abstract Algebra_, Part IV Chapter 13. Those are books that skip the examples and get immediately to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#Constructing_splitting_fields) is pretty good on this.

Factor $f$ into irreducible factors,  and form the quotient by one of those nonlinear factors, thereby getting an extension field with a new root of $f$.  You will need to do this at most $n$ times, where $n=\operatorname {deg}f$.